# Referencing websites in tex

Tags: bibliographies, links

I am writing a software report and I have to include Stack Exchange as a reference. Is it ever appropriate to include a link to the website? If I should have a clickable link, what are the options for achieving this in LaTeX or other TeX-based typesetting systems?

Comment: Actually, I don't know what I want. I need some advice if it is good practice to make a link to stackexchange.com if I'm mentioning Stack Exchange - and if it is good practice, whether it should be a footnote, reference to the bibliography, make the text itself clickable, etc.

Comment: Depending upon the style guide you are following the requirements for citing a web site or other electronic resource will differ.  You will need to comply with the correct style guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always use the package `hyperref` when I compile to PDFs. It makes internal links of the document clickable, and also features an `url` command, e.g. `\url{https://stackexchange.com}` will print the URL in monospace and make it clickable.

In my experience, it's convention to put hyperlinks in footnote (maybe with a small hint what's behind the link), except if they link to some publication worth a bibliography entry. But that probably depends on what and for who you are writing.

If you do not want the border around links, add the option `pdfborder={0 0 0}` to `hyperref`.

Comment: You should try the options `colorlinks` and `allcolors=black` one day.